# How to add a Boundary outline in UIView of Iphone.Please Read Description

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to make a rectangle Boundary and to insert a UITextView and two buttons in that rectangle .If i making the rectangle by adding a subView in a from  UIView class than I am unable to interact with the controls in the rectangle area which i inserted in the subview from Interface builder.

I am attaching a screen for that

[image: http://www.algoworks.com/images/img065842101.jpg]

In this image I have to make a rectangle and have to insert a text view and two Ui buttons.If I am making rectangle from UIView and adding in View Controller than the controls added in this subview from Interface builder doesn't responds.So I have to add these controls Programitically which create this task very tough.

Please Provide me a solution to make boundary of rectangle and than to add Controls.

Answer (score 12):

Just put all the controls in a container UIView and set the `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties of the container view's layer.

Answer (score 2):

Ole Begemann is correct in his post of borderWidth. One important addition though is that you need the following line.

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

mj

Comment: This should be a comment to that answer (or and edit of it) instead of a separate answer.